# How to only change one key of in a nested object with Strapi's PUT api

Tags: strapi

I a object in database and want to add value in a key ie: `key4` which is in a nested object using strapi's `PUT` api.

the Object:

```
obj: {
  id: 123,
  slug: "my-slug",
  blocks: [
    ...
  ]
  seo: {
    key1: 'key1',
    key2: 'key2',
    key3: {
      ...
    },
    key4: '',
  }
}
```

i am calling put api with axios
using it like this removes value from all the other keys and only sets value in `key4`

```
await axios({
  method: 'put',
  url: `${strapiBaseUrl}/objects/${obj.id}`,
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data: {
    data: {
      seo: {
        key4: 'test-url'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I hope you may find the answer in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71888370/how-to-update-array-using-put-api-request-in-strapi

Comment: @RamyNabil Thank you for the reply! And yes, I already am doing it like they suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71888370/how-to-update-array-using-put-api-request-in-strapi I just wanted to know if there is any other way around it as to not do spread for each level of the object.